# iOS 9 record video at 60fps

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Trying to record video at 60fps using AVFoundation and Swift, but code below is not working. Video still records at 30fps even though 60fps is set.

```
captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

var finalFormat = AVCaptureDeviceFormat()
var maxFps: Double = 0
for vFormat in camera!.formats
{
    var ranges      = vFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges as!  [AVFrameRateRange]
    let frameRates  = ranges[0]
    if frameRates.maxFrameRate >= maxFps && frameRates.maxFrameRate <= 60
    {
        maxFps = frameRates.maxFrameRate
        finalFormat = vFormat as! AVCaptureDeviceFormat
    }
}

print(String(maxFps) + " fps"); //prints 60 fps
try camera!.lockForConfiguration()
camera!.activeFormat = finalFormat
camera!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60)
camera!.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60)
camera!.unlockForConfiguration()

let video = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
captureSession!.addInput(video)

let audio = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
captureSession!.addInput(audio)

fileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

captureSession?.addOutput(fileOutput)

captureSession!.startRunning()
```

Comment: You know that only iphone 6 or newer, have this feature, right?

Comment: yes. i am testing with the iphone 6s

Comment: The device, using the native camera, records at 60fps?

Comment: yes. tested with both ipad and iphone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting camera properties after creating the AVCaptureDeviceInput works.

```
let video = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
captureSession!.addInput(video)

print(String(maxFps) + " fps"); //prints 60 fps
try camera!.lockForConfiguration()
camera!.activeFormat = finalFormat
camera!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60)
camera!.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60)
camera!.unlockForConfiguration()
```